# Mouse position on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, mouse, mouseover, mouse-position

Is it possible to get the exact mouse position in a mouseouver event of an image?
If I use a function that updates the mouse position on a document mouse move event, I can have problems with delay and this kind of thing and wouldn't get the EXACT position.

Comment: I think your going to have to elaborate, and some example code might also be nice. Also are we talking about Java or JavaScript/Web?

Comment: JavaScript, this is what i'm talking about

Answer (score 23):

If you are looking for a simple JS to get the cursor position for a MouseOver event, here is the sample code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script>
     
     function getPos(e){
      x=e.clientX;
      y=e.clientY;
      cursor="Your Mouse Position Is : " + x + " and " + y ;
      document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML=cursor
     }
    
     function stopTracking(){
      document.getElementById("displayArea").innerHTML="";
     }
    
     </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div id="focusArea" onmousemove="getPos(event)" onmouseout="stopTracking()"><p>Mouse Over This Text And Get The Cursor Position!</p></div>
     
     <p id="displayArea"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: with timer it could be even better (especially for CPU)

Comment: It seems for a mouseover event the clientX and clientY are undefined

Comment: cannot get lower value than 8px, and maximum size can be picked more than 100% width...

Answer (score 1):

The javascript method `offset()` used for tracking the position, and here I did the same as Mayur says, just little bit added.

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7P8Rr/)