# Tooltips with canvas networks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js

I've made a large force layout using D3.v4 and canvas. Because of the size I can't really use SVG.

How can I make tooltips for the elements on the canvas?

<strike>At the very least, how can I identify where the mouse is on the canvas?</strike>

I have tried to use the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545626/mouse-position-on-mouseover-event) question as inspiration to check where the mouse cursor is on the canvas and then use `simulation.find(x,y,radius)` to identify nearby nodes. However, that's returning a lot of false positives and I have a feeling that the HTML event and `simulation.find()` work differently and/or use different coordinate standards.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to this?

Edit: It was suggested to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas?rq=1) question. I have tried to do this, and it works, somewhat. The problem now is that, as suspected, `simulation.find(..)` doesn't seem to use these canvas coordinates to find nodes in the network.

For the curious, this is the current function I use to find the cursor and nearby nodes:

```
canvas = d3.select('canvas')
function getPos(e) {
    rect = canvas.node().getBoundingClientRect();
    scaleX = width / rect.width;
    scaleY = height / rect.height;
    x = (e.clientX - rect.left);
    y = (e.clientY - rect.top);
    node = simulation.find(x,y, 3);
    return {
        x : x,
        y : y,
        node : node
    };
}
```

Comment: If you add the event listener to the canvas then it only fires when the mouse is over the canvas

Comment: Did you read [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/real-mouse-position-in-canvas?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, that's as intended. I am curious, is the cursor position in `event` relative to the element that the event comes from?

Comment: No I didn't find that. Thanks @MikeC , I'll give it a try

Comment: While that does work, it unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the built-in [d3.mouse](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#mouse) to figure out position within the canvas:

```
d3.select("canvas").on("mousemove", function(d){
  var p = d3.mouse(this);
  var node = simulation.find(p[0], p[1]);
});
```

Here's a quick example which highlights the closest node to the mouse position:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<canvas width="960" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


  var graph = {};
  graph.nodes = d3.range(100).map(function(d) {
    return {
      id: d
    }
  });
  graph.links = d3.range(200).map(function(d) {
    return {
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
    };
  });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    graph.links.forEach(drawLink);
    context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode);
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.stroke();
    
    if (closeNode) {
      context.beginPath();
      drawNode(closeNode)
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
      context.stroke();
    }
  }
  
  var closeNode;
  d3.select("canvas").on("mousemove", function(d){
    var p = d3.mouse(this);
    closeNode = simulation.find(p[0], p[1]);
    ticked();
  })

  function drawLink(d) {
    context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
    context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
  }

  function drawNode(d) {
    context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
    context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Mark! I am facing a similar problem. Your approach works perfect. But, when I zoom in/out the network, then `simulation.find()` does not detect the correct node anymore. I tried to grab the current zoom level and update `d3.mouse(this)` coordinates by doing this `p[0]* currentZoom.k + currentZoom.x`, but not succesfully for the time being. Any recommendations?

Comment: @user3204834, you can use [transform.invert](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#transform_invert) to map the point to the transformed space. Update fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jyrzq1sL/).

Comment: Oh, that's correct! I needed the inverse transformation and not a new transformation. Thank you very much!